# Сверстать вертикальное меню при нажатии появляется подменю а пункт дополнительно отображается горизонтально

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: меню]

Не могу понять, как сделать чтобы пункты дублировались наверху, пока получилось сделать список и выпадающий список, подскажите плиз

```js
    let menuElem = document.getElementById('sweeties');
    let titleElem = menuElem.querySelector('.title');

    titleElem.onclick = function() {
      menuElem.classList.toggle('open');
    };
```

```css
    .menus ul {
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      display: none;
    }
    .menus .title {
      font-size: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menus.open ul {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
                       <ul class="leftblock-list">
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Каталог</a>
           <ul class="catalog-list">
              <li><a href="#">Автомобили</a></li>
              <li>

           <div id="sweeties"  class="menus">
                 <span class="title">Бытовая техника</span>
                 <ul class="product-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Микроволновки</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Холодильники</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Посудомоечные машины</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Чайники</a></li>
                 </ul>
       </div>


              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Мобильная техника</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Компьютеры</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Одежда</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Недвижимость</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: По картинке не совсем понятно) При нажатии на что именно, и чтобы что дублировалось?

Comment: Когда нажимаю  допустим  на "бытовую технику" выпадает список и "бытовая техника" дублируется наверху, главная--каталог --бытовая техника,как например каталог в интернет магазине, насколько я понимаю

Answer (score 1):

```js
let titles = document.querySelectorAll('.menus .title');

titles.forEach(function(title, i) {
  title.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let open = document.querySelector('.menus .open');
    if (open) open.classList.remove('open');

    let products = document.querySelectorAll('.menus .product-list');
    products[i].classList.add('open');
    
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = this.textContent;
  });
});
```

```css
.menus .product-list {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menus .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menus .product-list.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Ляляля... / <span id="demo"></span>
<hr>

<div class="menus">
  <div class="title">Бытовая техника</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><a href="#">Микроволновки</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Холодильники</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Посудомоечные машины</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Чайники</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="title">Bubu</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="title">Moo</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

То же самое могло бы быть написано через обычный перебор:

```
for( let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++ ){
  titles[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    //...

    products[i].classList.add('open');
    //...
  });
}
```

Ключевая фишка именно в том, чтобы как-то запомнить номер `i` для кликнутой кнопки и использовать его, чтобы достать нужный список продуктов.

---

P.s. Извращение на тему

> @Sevastopol': А если большая вложенность?

```js
let title = document.querySelectorAll('.menus .title');

for (let i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
  title[i].addEventListener('click', mainBubuHandler);
}

/***/

function mainBubuHandler(i){
  let otherActives = find(this.parentNode, '.active');  
  removeClass(otherActives, 'active');
  
  addClass(this, 'active');  
  addClass(this.nextElementSibling, 'active');
  
  updatePath();
}

function updatePath() {
  let actives = document.querySelectorAll('.menus .active.title');
  let path = [...actives].map(e => e.textContent).join("/");
  
  document.getElementById('path').textContent = "Root://" + path;
}

/* Lib */

function find(elems, selector){
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return elems.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }

  var all = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    all.concat( elems[i].querySelectorAll(selector) );
  }
  return all;
}

function siblings(elem, selector){
  var all = elem.parentElement.children;
  var callback = function(el) {
    return (el !== elem) && el.matches(selector);
  };
  return [].filter.call(all, callback);
}

function removeClass(elems, className) {
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return elems.classList.remove(className);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].classList.remove(className);
  }
}

function addClass(elems, className) {
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return elems.classList.add(className);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].classList.add(className);
  }
}
```

```css
.product-list {
  display: none;
}

.title {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title.active {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.product-list.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="path">Root://</div>
<hr>

<div class="menus">
  <div class="title">Bubu-1</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li>
      <div class="title">main-111</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-222</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-333</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="title">Bubu-2</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li>
      <div class="title">main-111</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-222</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-333</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="title">Bubu-3</div>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li>
      <div class="title">main-111</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-222</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="title">main-333</div>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>sub-111</li>
        <li>sub-222</li>
        <li>sub-333</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' Добавил в ответ, но не знаю, насколько читаемый код... критика приветствуется))